# How to configure javadocs for AEM CQ5.6?

Tags: javadoc, aem

I am learning CQ 5.6. I am struggling to enable context help in jsps in CRDXE eclipse. My question is :

> Where can I obtain javadocs **jars** for cq libraries like cq-wcm-api-5.6.4.jar?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know they are not available via Maven. But you can reference them from the web (CQ 5.6.1):
http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/javadoc/overview-summary.html

And if you are considering the latest version now called AEM 6:
http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/develop/ref/javadoc/overview-summary.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Thomas. But I am looking for **javadoc jars** and not online documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there aren't any.  If you want to see the internals or something other than online docs you'll have to decompile the jars.